# CorelDraw to pdf color washing out

Tags: print-design, corel-draw

I'm pretty new to CorelDraw, coming from a background of Photoshop. Now I'm designing a Brochure which needs to be done in CorelDraw and exported to PDF for printing. I believe the press only prints in CMYK color mode.

While I publishing the CorelDraw design to PDF the colors the washing out. I think I'm missing some configuration.

I can fix this by changing PDF generating settings which saving the PDF in RGB mode. But this might affect the printing, any suggestions will be helpful.

Another thing is I'm using some gradient effects. Will these be printed in good quality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to look into some color calibration.

Some tips I wouls give you is take your design to a local printers such as UPS or FedEx and you could order a single run proof.   I would also look into a CMYK color book to know what CMYK values you should use and it helps in the color calibration.

In regards to graidents I would highly advice looking into greating halftones so they turn out better.  Gradients in print always act different than gradients in web.

Now in regards to CorelDraw it would be better to use InDesign and export as a PDF or even in Illustrator and export to PDF.

If any of the above havent answered your question than edit it because you dont mention if you calibrated your equipment, which is monitor, printer, and computer.